# Disable some feauture while building Gstreamer Lib which cause Error?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm build gstreamer, at the step of building gstpgood/ext/aalib
The error log is

```
    make[3]: Entering directory `sigma-gstreamer_1-2-rc5/build/gstpgood/ext'
    make -C aalib
    make[4]: Entering directory `/sigma-gstreamer_1-2-rc5/build/gstpgood/ext/aalib'
    CC       libgstaasink_la-gstaasink.lo
    cc1: error: include location "/usr/include" is unsafe for cross-compilation  [-Werror=poison-system-directories]
    cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
    make[4]: *** [libgstaasink_la-gstaasink.lo] Error 1
```

My friend build the same source on the other build host did not get this error. I compared gstpgood makefiles and found that my makefile has:

```
AALIB_CFLAGS = -I/usr/include
AALIB_CONFIG = /usr/bin/aalib-config
AALIB_LIBS = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -laa
```

while my friend's make file has

```
AALIB_CFLAGS = 
AALIB_CONFIG = no
AALIB_LIBS =
```

This aalib is used by aasink, how can i disable aasink when compiling gstreamer???

Answer (score 0):

Pass --disable-aalib to configure before running make. Check ./configure --help for many other things you could disable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Sebastian Dröge!
I also find a way to bypass aalib check by editing .m4 file in: gstreamer/ext/gstpgood/m4/aalib.m4 it worked for me

```
#force disable aalibtes by putting  enable_aalibtest=no
AC_ARG_ENABLE(aalibtest, 
  AC_HELP_STRING([--disable-aalibtest],
             [do not try to compile and run a test AALIB program]),
  , enable_aalibtest=yes)
enable_aalibtest=no


#comment some code
#  AC_PATH_PROG(AALIB_CONFIG, aalib-config, no)
#  min_aalib_version=ifelse([$1], ,0.11.0,$1)
#  AC_MSG_CHECKING(for AALIB - version >= $min_aalib_version)
  no_aalib=""

#  if test "$AALIB_CONFIG" = "no" ; then
  if test x$aalib_prefix == x ; then#add this line
    no_aalib=yes
  else
    AALIB_CFLAGS="-I$aalib_prefix/include"#add this line
    AALIB_LIBS="-L$aalib_prefix/lib -laa"#add this line
# AALIB_CFLAGS=`$AALIB_CONFIG $aalibconf_args --cflags`
# AALIB_LIBS=`$AALIB_CONFIG $aalibconf_args --libs`

# aalib_major_version=`$AALIB_CONFIG $aalib_args --version | \
#   sed 's/\([[0-9]]*\).\([[0-9]]*\).\([[0-9]]*\)/\1/'`
# aalib_minor_version=`$AALIB_CONFIG $aalib_args --version | \
#   sed 's/\([[0-9]]*\).\([[0-9]]*\).\([[0-9]]*\)/\2/'`
# aalib_micro_version=`$AALIB_CONFIG $aalib_config_args --version | \
#   sed 's/\([[0-9]]*\).\([[0-9]]*\).\([[0-9]]*\)/\3/'`
```